# Should I have FKs pointing to data that rarely changes, or just stick the data in directly?

Tags: sql

Say that I have a few tables that never change, such as a 'State' (referring to U.S. states) or 'Country' table. If I then have a Customer table which stores information such as CustomerState, CustomerCountry, is it really necessary to store them as the FK to the respective table?

The values are populated from forms that pull the appropriate data from State or Country (i.e. states will always be going in as their correct 2-letter codes - users can't enter custom input or anything fishy like that).

I ask because it seems like adding extra joins for something so simple will just slow queries down. This isn't an issue for me now since I work on a tiny database...but someday I might not. Does it even matter? Is the performance loss so insignificant that I should just do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The design rule of thumb here is that if the set of values has low cardinality and its members are stable (though not necessarily immutable) then use a `CHECK` constraint (example: [ISO 5218 sex codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_5218)). Otherwise, use a look table with a foreign key.

Note that some nation states (borders and names) are less stable than others :) `CustomerCountry` may have different meanings for different consumers. Think of all the variations of my country's name that you could put on an item of snail mail (UK, Great Britain, The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, Angleterre, etc) and still expect it to be delivered, whereas your application logic may want to work exclusively with the value `ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 = 'GBR'`

Note that in mySQL although using a `CHECK` constraint is valid syntax it never actually gets checked, so I suppose, then, the rule of thumb for mySQL is to always use a lookup table with a foreign key!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, store them as a separate table. The key (and foreign key) can be char(2).

At *some* point you will have:

- data modification anomalies
- another data entry client
- a bulk upload
- a new state (Baja Arizona, anyone?)
- some extra info to add to the state table for the state entity
- a bollixed release
- ...

Comment: +1 : `some extra info to add to the state table for the state entity`.  The states may not change, but your use of them may change, requiring the design to require growth.  The separation is extremely useful for such future maintainability of the design.

Answer (score 1):

Having relationships is a good design approach/practice.

As far as performance is concerned, as you yourself said, it is insignificant/negligible!

Comment: Well, it's insignificant in my tiny, sub-1 million row database. I'm curious how it plays out meatier databases.

Comment: You seem to under-estimate the power of modern RDBMS! Until you are hit with such an issue, then only consider performance optimization. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming" - Donald E. Knuth

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a matter of how correct you want your design to be. I would always create a separate look up table, with foreign key lookup. Only when a performance issue was raised would I look at changing it. But then, I'm a database designer, and think all the business rules should be in the database, and enforced from there.

Comment: Agreed - only do funky things like denormaliztion (the term for not using a lookup) if performance requirements demand it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. And for many reasons :

- It avoids data redundancy.
- It decreases index tables sizes if you use these columns as indexes. Instead of indexing a character string, it indexes integers.
- You will get your data faster: comparing character strings is much longer than comparing two integers :)

And probably many other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't both with a 'State' table in my designs. Like you said, the user will probably not be able to enter an invalid state typically as the input comes from a dropdown.

But, to answer your other question about performance, I don't think you will find it will slow it down either if you did the join.  You need to remember that SQL will cache data in RAM and for very small tables, it will just cache the entire table, so there is no I/O hit after the first access.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do early optimization! Supposing you have a design/architecture which supports database refactoring, I'd suggest you to postpone your performance motivated denormalization until you have a real performance problem. You might save yourself some headaches.

Answer (score 0):

My attitude here is just a little different. *If* I had a State table, then I would use the official abbreviation as the PK anyway. Defining it as char(2), I wouldn't expect to have the (modest) overhead of an index of long strings. I would not add an identity column. In this scenario, you don't have to decide now whether you need the table or not. If later you want more columns for a State object (e.g., sales tax rate), you make the table and just add an FK relationship from your long-standing Customer table.