# Is it necessary to create a table for all repeated data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-normalization

I hope this doesn't come across as too much of a stupid question. I'm slightly confused by the concepts of database normalisation, it seems to suggest that where there is any sort of predictable or repeated data in a particular field/column then it's best to create a new table and link by foreign ID, is this really necessary for every situation?

For example, fields like ***Gender***, ***Business Type*** (has no strict functional purpose, just information), ***Salutation*** (Mr, Mrs etc), all these will be repeated throughout the table bit it seems a bit over the top and hassling to me to have to create a new table for these? It also mans I have to use a lot more JOINs when retrieving data.

At which point does it become necessary to use separate tables for repeated data, or is it best practice to do it for everything?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226852/should-i-have-fks-pointing-to-data-that-rarely-changes-or-just-stick-the-data-in/6227325#6227325).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I have FKs pointing to data that rarely changes, or just stick the data in directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226852/should-i-have-fks-pointing-to-data-that-rarely-changes-or-just-stick-the-data-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I recommend using ENUMs when you care about correct data entry. For instance, if you want to find all people whose gender is MALE, it would be great if you could guarantee the gender field will always have an uppercase M in it, not a lowercase m, or a G for "guy" because the front-end application contained a bug.

If you care about correct data entry and there's additional information associated with the concept, I recommend factoring it out into a separate table. For instance, if "business type" is associated with TAX_RATE, you probably want to create a business_types table.

If you trust your front-end application and you have no real business logic associated to a field - and there are no inherent business constraints on the data, e.g. in salutation, just have a varchar field in which the front-end can dump its data.

Comment: @Mark-Bannister there are no any arguments about not using ENUM.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm slightly confused by the concepts of database normalisation, it
>   seems to suggest that where there is any sort of predictable or
>   repeated data in a particular field/column then it's best to create a
>   new table and link by foreign ID, is this really necessary for every
>   situation?

You're reading the wrong book. Normalization sometimes involves moving attributes from one relation to another; normalization never involves substituting an ID number for text.

You use an additional table when you need a certain kind of control over the values a user is allowed to put into a column.

To restrict the values users are allowed to enter into a column, such as "Business type", you can add a table that has all the known, valid values, then set a foreign key reference to it.

You can also restrict values with a CHECK constraint, but when you discover a new, valid value, you have to alter the schema. If you use a table and a foreign key constraint, you just have to insert a row into the table. In your case, a CHECK constraint would be suitable for "gender"; tables would probably be better for "business type" and "salutation".

Answer (score 3):

Removing any single attribute to another table and replacing it with another single attribute representing the same thing has nothing to do with normalization. It may or may not be useful to do such a thing for other reasons but it isn't normalization.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use common sense.
Unless genetics come up with something new you can safely use M/F values in Gender field (beware localisation of course).
You need separate table for these lists that tend to be dynamic - so all possible options can be obtained from one place.

Comment: Gender codes are application-specific. ISO 5218 defines four: male, female, unknown, and not applicable. ("Not applicable" makes you wonder, doesn't it?) But some applications might need to distinguish males at birth from males following gender reassignment. But the more important point is that normalization is a hard science (well, hard-ish, with allowances for semantics); common sense, in the form of "you can have your opinion; I can have my opinion", doesn't really have a place.

Answer (score 1):

For things like gender I would say a simple CHAR field would suffice. ie 'M','F','U' (unknown). However for Business Type I would advise breaking this out into a separate table. For one thing the business type will probably be reasonably long, you may need to add more at any given time, and you may wish to change a business type.

Answer (score 1):

The point of normalization is to make sure that the same information *about one entity* is not stored twice (because it could, and probably would, get inconsistent). Clearly, different entities in the same table will have the same fields, and of course many of them will e F and many M. That is not a concern. The only thing you should not do is store redundant data *per record*, such as GENDER:f,TERM_OF_ADDRESS:Ms - that is really better done via a lookup table.

Also, you don't need to normalize just because different tables in your schema have similar fields, such as TYPE or GENDER. Just make sure that those really are independent tables! For instance, if you describe employees in a table EMPLOYEE, and that table contains gender information, than gender should probably not also be stored in a linked HEALTH_RECORD table, even though it could be medically relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ENUM(Mr, Mrs) or ENUM(Male,Female) for such data.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html

Comment: Sorry, Andrej, I thought I had left a comment here. It is "-1 for using ENUMs."

Comment: Could you explain your idea? Enums is ideally for columns like Gender/Types or which have static values. Also they are optimized in Mysql for searching.

Comment: Cancelled downvote. My original objection was that, since this is a normalisation question rather than a MySQL-specific question, a MySQL-specific technique (such as an ENUM) would be less helpful than a more widely applicable technique, such as a check constraint. However, I have since checked and it appears that the only way of implementing a check constraint in MySQL is as an ENUM!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fully normalised databse design, then, yes, you should put any repeating entities in a separate table.

For a field like *gender*, it would give the benefit of containing descriptive information like Male/Female, rather than codes like M/F, or True/False.

On the other hand, as you say, each new table makes it more complicated to get at the data, so in practice you try to find a balance that is fairly well normalised.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: None of the normal forms ask whether there are repeated values in a column. Should you find repeated values in a column, none of the normal forms require you to create an additional table without changing the original table. This isn't normalization; it's an entirely different aspect of database design.

Comment: @Catcall: By "repeated values" i mean values that represent the same entity. For gender, for example, "Male" would always represent the same gender, they are not separate genders that happen to have the same name. Of course you should not just create a new table without changing the original table.

Comment: The OP is talking about values repeating in a column; multiple "M"s, one for each male, multiple "F"s, one for each female. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Catcall: Perhaps it's clearer for the *Business Type* field, where there are more options, and they can't easily be substituted for short codes. Repeating the name of a business type over and over is redundant, so it should be normalised.

Comment: Then I did understand you correctly. The problem is that you're completely mistaken. Normalization doesn't involve replacing values with id numbers. Normalization doesn't involve replacing values with short codes for values. Normalization involves **removing columns** from one table, and **inserting those same columns** into a different table. Repeating the name of a business type in multiple rows of a table is no less redundant than repeating the id number of a business type in multiple rows of a table, or repeating the short code for a business type in multiple rows of a table.

Comment: @Catcall: Of course repeated values is redundant. I suggest that you read up on basic normalisation theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Comment: Removing any single attribute to another table and replacing it with another single attribute representing the same thing has nothing to do with normalization. It doesn't matter whether the values are "repeated" or whether they are "short codes" or not. 2NF, 3NF, BCNF, 4NF, 5NF, etc are solely concerned with removing *non-key dependencies* and are entirely agnostic about what type of data an attribute consists of.

Comment: @dportas: I think that Catcall is confusing you. Please read what I have written, and not what he thinks that I have written. Moving a repeated entity into a separate table and putting the corresponding foreign key in its place removes the redundancy, which is what normalisation is basically about.

Comment: @Guffa: What you wrote was that for a "fully normalised databse design ... put any repeating entities in a separate table". That's incorrect if by "repeating entities" you mean any single attribute like "busines type". Replacing an attribute with a foreign key doesn't eliminate any redundancy in logical terms because the new FK values are repeated just exactly as the old values were. I expect you mean that the old value could be replaced by a new one requiring less storage. That has nothing to do with normalization though, which is specifically about redundancy due to non-key dependencies.

Comment: @Guffa you misunderstand what database normalization is. I too once thought the same and struggled with this concept but what catcall is saying is right